# Tags of the week! April 8-14, 2019: Punctuation & Naming — RESULTS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

## WEEK: April 8-14, 2019
TAGS: [punctuation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) and [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming)

---

## Results

Our second tag promo week kept the momentum going with 7 new questions from 6 users.

**And our winner is... Linksassin.**

Congrats.  Linksassin posted 2 questions, both in [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming).  Linksassin's special prize is running the week 3 promo!  Woo hoo!

Honorable mentions to Lauren Ipsum, Liquid, bruglesco, and Evil Sparrow for asking questions about [punctuation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) and Monica Cellio for a question about [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming)

---

As a followup to our [fantastic tag contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/announcing-our-contest-results?cb=1), and to suggestions that we [continue the fun](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/suggestion-continue-question-pushes/1955) in a more informal way, here is Writing.SE's second:

## TAGS OF THE WEEK PROMO

### Rules:

- The contest runs for one week, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or both of the tags of the week.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the week, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use both tags in the same question.

---

**Notes:**

- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this week's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal is to increase questions on tags that have not yet reached the magic 200 questions.  My personal focus is tags that are in the top 40 tags but under 200 questions.
- Others may take over other weeks and they may have different goals.
- Each week we'll have two tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

Comment: I had this nagging feeling I'd forgotten something!  Thanks Monica.

Comment: I wonder if we should tag these as 'tag-challenge' rather than 'contest' hopefully this will be a long running thing and it's not really a contest.

Comment: @linksassin Monica added that tag and it seems okay to me, I mean it's just a tag not the title or anything.  I don't want to invent a new tag to say "it's like a contest but not really one ya know."

Comment: @MonicaCellio Do you have an opinion on this? Other sites have a 'weekly-challenge' meta tag. I just feel 'contest' is a bit misleading if we use it for both things with prizes and things without.

Comment: I'm actually trying to script my podcast about punctuation now -- the problem is it's called "Alphabetical April," but there are no pieces of punctuation that seem to fit the letters H, Y, and Z, and my terms for J, K, L, and X are stretches.   I don't know what questions I can ask (or ask/answer) that wouldn't fit more in EnglishUsage, though.  I can't post it as a question, because that would be more of a "tell me what to write" type. hmmm....

Comment: @linksassin I don't object to creating a different tag.  I thought it might be useful to keep all our contests, competitions, challenges, etc together on one tag, to make finding what we've done in the past easier when we're considering something new.  Maybe the problem is the name?  The contest tag was created years ago for a different contest, so I reused that.

Comment: @linksassin and others, I would say that the tag should be called promos, but we already have the tag [tag:site-promotion] and it has a somewhat different meaning.  What if we kept [tag:contests] and just put appropriate wiki in there?  Right now it has none.

Comment: So every punctuation question I can come up with has been already asked and answered.  Even one I searched for extensively finally came up.  That's when I realized that tagging was off. If you try to search for "punctuation" it only shows you questions that use the tag.  To search for the keyword, you must go out of your way to do so. So I'm retagging posts about punctuation that don't use the tag (with other edits if required). Trying to only do a few at a time as not to flood the homepage.  Consider this my contribution to this tag.  :-)

Comment: @Cyn - that is a HUGE contribution!  Di you know how many you've changed?  I wonder if other of our under-200 tags are actually close to 200, just due to mislabeling?

Comment: @April I am shocked by how badly mislabeled [tag:punctuation] is.  I have done other tag cleanups and they were a fraction of this.  It's possible the tag was created after the bulk of the questions, but I'm not sure.  A lot of duplicate questions and others that really don't belong in writing, but they're old and I'm not flagging them.  Right now [tag:punctuation] is at 166 questions and I'm holding back (to keep from totally flooding the home page).  I've done probably over 3/4 of them but I'm not sure.  The tag started at 117 IIRC. It does make me wonder how many other tags need work.

Comment: @April 182 questions.  I'm done for now.  If we pay attention going forward, [tag:punctuation] will be over 200 in no time.  I think it's just one of those tags people don't think about using, even when (in retrospect) it's obvious.  And it's not one where it's easy to find either, by searching for a keyword.  There were tons of questions that only mentioned the names of one or more punctuation marks, but not the word "punctuation" itself.

Comment: I'm finding these tags of the week a good opportunity to check for missed tags in old posts.  Just finished [tag:naming] and there were only a fraction of missed tags compared to [tag:punctuation].  But wow tons of duplicate and overly broad questions.  The fun part is that a lot of people are answering these old questions as they find them in the queue.  I love that we get to improve them.

Comment: @Cyn Perhaps that should actually be an official part of the focus of these tag-challenges? I'll bet if we could re-tag everything on the site we would use less tags but would have qualified for the generalist badge already

Comment: @linksassin If anyone else wants to join in, go for it.  I actually enjoy editing and etc but there's no reason it has to be me.  I'm going to go back to last week and do [tag:poetry] and [tag:nonfiction] but not until tomorrow.  We do need to be mindful of not flooding the homepage with "new" posts that are our edits of old ones.  Because you get the same queue bump with a retag as with a full edit, I'm taking the time to do full edits where warranted.

Comment: I also adjust other tags if needed (my personal choice is not to remove tags on old posts if they are popular ones, because it messes with people's tag badges but I do remove ones barely used...just removed one that the person made up and no one else ever used).

Comment: [tag:poetry] and [tag:nonfiction] are now done.  They didn't have very many retags.  [tag:punctuation] was special.

Comment: Okay folks, it's almost time for Week 3!  Does anyone want to take a swing at it?  I don't mind continuing but I'm happy to hand the torch over.  All you have to do is pick two tags to feature, copy and paste this week's question into a new one, edit it, add the answer to get people started (check the community wiki box) and total the answers at the end.  How about you, @linksassin ?

Comment: @Cyn Sure I'll take it on for a week. Question [here](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1974/33442) just needs a featured tag.

Comment: @linksassin cool.  Monica will take care of the tag.  It's 9 minutes into Monday for SE (even though it's only 5:09pm for me).  Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

Linksassin (2)

- [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) [How to create a consistent feel for character names in a fantasy setting?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44462/33442)
- [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) [How to create place names that feel like they belong to a culture?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44569/33442)

Lauren Ipsum (1)

- [punctuation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) [Punctuating text messages with speaker tags in running copy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44481/punctuating-text-messages-with-speaker-tags-in-running-copy)

Liquid (1)

- [punctuation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) [The difference between dialogue marks](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44502/the-difference-between-dialog-marks)

bruglesco (1)

- [punctuation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) [Elongated vowel sounds](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/elongated-vowel-sounds)

Evil Sparrow (1)

- [punctuation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) [Correct punctuation for showing a character's confusion](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44563/correct-punctuation-for-showing-a-characters-confusion)

Monica Cellio (1)

- [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) [How can I make names more distinctive without making them longer?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44609/how-can-i-make-names-more-distinctive-without-making-them-longer)